# Pandas: Groupby to create table with count and count values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My objective is simple but not sure if it's possible. Reproducible example:

Can you go from this:

```
raw_data = {'score': [1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2],
        'player': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'George', 'Cooze', 'Wilkinson', 'Lewis', 'Lewis', 'Lewis', 'Jacobson']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['score', 'player'])
df

    score   player
0   1       Miller
1   3       Jacobson
2   4       Ali
3   4       George
4   1       Cooze
5   2       Wilkinson
6   2       Lewis
7   4       Lewis
8   4       Lewis
9   2       Jacobson
```

To this:

```
        score    col_1       col_2       col_3       col_4     
score   
1       2        Miller      Cooze       n/a         n/a
2       3        Wilkinson   Lewis       Jacobson    n/a
3       1        Jacobson    n/a         n/a         n/a
4       4        Ali         George      Lewis       Lewis
```

Via a `groupby`?

I can get this far `df.groupby(['score']).agg({'score': np.size})` but can't work out how to create the new columns with the column values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can duplicate your output with

**Option 1**

```
g = df.groupby('score').player
g.size().to_frame('score').join(g.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('col_'))

       score      col_0   col_1     col_2  col_3
score                                           
1          2     Miller   Cooze       NaN    NaN
2          3  Wilkinson   Lewis  Jacobson    NaN
3          1   Jacobson     NaN       NaN    NaN
4          4        Ali  George     Lewis  Lewis
```

**Option 2**

```
d1 = df.groupby('score').agg({'score': 'size', 'player': lambda x: tuple(x)})
d1.join(pd.DataFrame(d1.pop('player').values.tolist()).add_prefix('col_'))

       score      col_0   col_1     col_2  col_3
score                                           
1          2     Miller   Cooze       NaN    NaN
2          3  Wilkinson   Lewis  Jacobson    NaN
3          1   Jacobson     NaN       NaN    NaN
4          4        Ali  George     Lewis  Lewis
```

Comment: @MaxU I used `pop`!  I'm so proud of myself :-)

Comment: Both gorgeous. I don't get the correct output for option 2 (possibly because I'm using Python 3?). Nonetheless, option 1 is perfect.